# iOS 6 - How to post tweet from a twitter account that is not on the user's device

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm in the very early planning stages of building another iOS app.  I'm hoping to be able to post tweets to my own account when users take specific actions from within an iOS 6 app.  That is, I want to authenticate to twitter as a user that is not stored on the user's device.  Is it possible to use the Social and Accounts frameworks to accomplish this, or should I be investigating another framework?  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

cheers,
a

Comment: Just realize that whatever method you use, somebody will extract the auth token and start posting random messages to the account. This is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for this Mike.  That is disappointing news.  Is there really no way around this?  It seems a simple enough request.  To have an app securely post information to twitter (or facebook) to a third-party twitter account (or facebook fan page).

Comment: I suppose I could just use the Social Framework as normal, and post the tweet under the app user's name but prefaced with '@myAccount' so that the tweets show up in my feed.  Still, if there's a way to securely post the tweet under my account, that would be best.

Comment: I wonder if you ought to use a tool such as Flurry analytics to track this stuff.  It is super easy to implement.